# Atmel-Ice Debugging with software breakpoints (SAMD21, SWD)

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, breakpoints, atmelstudio

I've been getting various issues while trying to set software breakpoints in Atmel Studio 7 with the Atmel-ICE debugger using SWD. I was wondering if anyone could explain in more detail (or point me in the direction of documentation) to give me a better understanding as to why I get the following issues:

1. Breakpoints being moved upon compilation
2. Being 'Unable to set requested breakpoint on target'
3. Breakpoint only being hit the first time in a loop

The following code is a test program I wrote to demonstrate this using the delay routines and the PORT driver of the ASF:

```
#include <asf.h>
#define LED PIN_PA01

int main (void)
{
  system_init();
  delay_init();
  struct port_config config_port_pin;
  config_port_pin.direction = PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT;
  port_pin_set_config(LED, &config_port_pin);

  while(1)
  {
    port_pin_toggle_output_level(LED);
    delay_ms(100);
  }
}
```

1. If a breakpoint is set at the LED toggle line then the breakpoint is moved to the following delay line.
2. If the delay is commented out and a breakpoint placed at the LED toggle line then it tells me it is unable to set requested breakpoint on target
3. If a breakpoint is placed on the delay line it only gets hit (the program halts) on the first iteration of the while loop. If I continue (F5) the program keeps running ( LED toggles every 100 ms) but doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

The code runs fine as far as I'm aware. The LED toggles every 100 ms as expected when I run without debugging, it is just the software breakpoints that I don't quite understand, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: It is due to compiler optimization level. Disable all optimization flags and generated code will be exactly what you wrote and you'll be able to set breakpoints where you want using your [tag:c] source code.

Comment: @LPs : That looks like an answer not a comment.  It would be legitimate here to ask what compiler options are set,  but if you are going to assert the cause and offer a solution that you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Clifford Maybe, yes, I see your point. I usually avoid post such an answer if the context is not really clear: it is too vague As you wrote I don't really know what is the compiler OP is using so I cannot suggest which compiler option to remove/change.

Comment: @LPs : The problem is that if you guessed right,(and i suspect you did), the OP may never clarify, because his problem is solved, and the community benefit is of little interest to him. Alternatively, someone else may post your answer and claim credit!

Comment: What compiler and compiler options are you applying?

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I agree. Sincerely I'm very bored of users posting questions without give answers to clarifications required by comments and my instinctive reaction was to stop asking and try to guess. In this specific case it's quite obvious.. BTW I'll take note of your position I'll try to apply it in future. ;)

Comment: Probably the most informative thing to do would be to try to switch to a mixed source and assembly view and see where the breakpoints end up.  As for the compiler options, they are presumably buried in menus of the Atmel Studio IDE, though on compilation a makefile is generated where the actual arm-none-eabi-gcc invocations with options can be seen.

Comment: The compiler settings will also be evident in the raw build log.

Comment: @LPs Thanks I had a read a bit more about compiler optimization and have solved these issues, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i know you answered your problem but this is really good tutorial someone wrote
about optimization of compiler

https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tutcoptimization-and-importance-volatile-gcc